# How to send JSON values to another activity, Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

So, I have a list that gets its values from JSON:

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnXF6.png)

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray paises = jsonObject.optJSONArray("paises");

                    if (paises != null) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < paises.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = paises.getJSONObject(j);
                            System.out.println(jsonObject1.optString("Designacao"));
                            String K_PAIS = jsonObject1.getString("K_PAIS");
                            String Designacao = jsonObject1.getString("Designacao");
                            String URL_IMAGE_SMALL = jsonObject1.getString("URL_IMAGE_SMALL");
                            String Coord_LAT = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_LAT");
                            String Coord_LONG = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_LONG");
                            String Coord_Zoom = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_Zoom");

                            HashMap<String, String> pais = new HashMap<>();

                            pais.put("K_PAIS", K_PAIS);
                            pais.put("Designacao", Designacao);
                            pais.put("URL_IMAGE_SMALL", URL_IMAGE_SMALL);
                            pais.put("URL_IMAGEM", URL_IMAGEM);
                            pais.put("Coord_LAT",Coord_LAT);
                            pais.put("Coord_LONG",Coord_LONG);
                            pais.put("Coord_Zoom",Coord_Zoom);
                            listaPaises.add(pais);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And now I want to send those value to my next activity.
This is my Click listener:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(  ,  );
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

I know it's something like `intent.putExtra(  ,  );`, but I don't know what variable to send because the values are different from item to item.
How can I do this?

Comment: make an object and send

Comment: Or if an array is to be passed then also no problem. make an oject array and send

Comment: So.. the array must be created after the HashMap code? Inside the for?

Comment: create the array whereeve you wish but it must be done before this event call

Comment: Are you downloading data and attaching it to list view?

Comment: You cannot directly send an object as extra for intent, you have to make it Serializable/Parcelable. Other way around you can convert the required JSONArray/JSONObject to String pass it as extra and convert back to JSONArray/JSONObject and use it in the new activity.

Comment: yes i missed that

Answer (score 1):

Create an object implementing `Serializable`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Example implements Serializable {

    private String mName;
    private String mId;
    private int mNumber;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return mNumber;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        mNumber = number;
    }
}
```

Then you can put this extra and get it as `getSerializableExtra()`

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EXAMPLE, example);
```

---

```
Example example = (Example) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_EXAMPLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> listpais= new ArrayList<String>(); // make this global   
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray paises = jsonObject.optJSONArray("paises");

                        if (paises != null) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < paises.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = paises.getJSONObject(j);
                                System.out.println(jsonObject1.optString("Designacao"));
                                String K_PAIS = jsonObject1.getString("K_PAIS");
                                String Designacao = jsonObject1.getString("Designacao");
                                String URL_IMAGE_SMALL = jsonObject1.getString("URL_IMAGE_SMALL");
                                String Coord_LAT = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_LAT");
                                String Coord_LONG = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_LONG");
                                String Coord_Zoom = jsonObject1.getString("Coord_Zoom");

                                someClass xyz= new someClass();

                                xyz.var1=K_data1;
                                xyz.var2=K_data2;
                                xyz.var3=K_data3;
                                xyz.var4=K_data4;
                                xyz.var5=K_data5;

                                listaPaises.add(xyz);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

and

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(  "data1", listpais );
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: and make xyz as marc said

Comment: it returns null

Comment: first using toast check if the data is coming or not and check where you are getting null

Comment: So... Using  "listaPaises.add(xyz);" gives me a error: "add(java.lang.String) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (com.example.abili.project.someClass)" it says to change  "ArrayList<String> listaPaises = new ArrayList<String>();" to "ArrayList<someClass> listaPaises = new ArrayList<>();"

Comment: did u completely copied my code?

Comment: In my code the arraylist which i created is different with the one which i added. make sure both are same

Comment: Yes there was just one thing that you wrote wrong "listpais", at least I think  it was just a mistake because what I had was listaPaises

Comment: So there is two different arraylist?

Comment: no. not at all. that was mistake in hurry both are same.

Comment: It doesn't let add xyz to listaPaises: "add(java.lang.String) in ArrayList cannot be applied"

Answer (score 0):

make a method to get clicked item inside adapter like below

```
public Object getItemByPosition(int position){
//Array is your array of objects defined inside the adapter
return array.get(position).toString();
}
```

then inside your Item click listerner you can do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("your_key",  adapter.getItemByPosition(position));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: And how he has the adapter in the new activity? to call adapter.getItemByPosition()